# overflow working with display inline

Tags: html, css

Overflow doesn't appear to be working when I use display: inline.  I need to have the text inline, because it's something that appears at the top right of the webpage with "Hello," in front of it and a drop down arrow behind the name.  If I remove the display: inline, the overflow works, but then the word in front and the image behind the name drops to a new row.  I tried using inline-block, but that causes the text to actually wrap, though it's hidden, the name looks like I superscript it.

[image: example]

How can I make this work property?

```css
div.actualName {
  display: inline;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
This is
<div class="actualName">Bobby Joe Sanders</div>computer.
<br/>
```

Comment: Is your problem that your content is not staying in the same line, rather wrapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inline-block` but add the `vertical-align:top` rule. The default vertical alignment for inline elements is baseline.

```css
div.actualName {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
This is
<div class="actualName">Bobby Joe Sanders</div>computer.
<br/>
```

Comment: perfect.  I've never used baseline.   After looking up, what that is for, it still doesn't make sense why it pushed the text up over the baseline of text already there.   Oh well, this answers my question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using a styled **span** might be more useful in this particular example versus applying a **div** and **class** to style a few words in your line of text. Spans are more similar to in-line elements while divs are more like block elements. Let me know if it helps! Good luck.

Comment: Span, didn't apply the overflow: hidden.